# What system was Grothendieck working in when he introduced universes?

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, math-history

I was reading that the universes which we now call "Grothendieck universes" were introduced by Grothendieck in order to avoid proper classes; from 
[Grothendieck universe on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_universe):

> The idea of universes is due to Alexander Grothendieck, who used them as a way of avoiding proper classes in algebraic geometry.

Now, the existence of such universes is axiomatized formally by Tarski's axiom in [Tarski–Grothendieck set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory):

> For every set $x$, there exists a set $y$ whose members include:
>
> - $x$ itself;
> - every subset of every member of $y$;
> - the power set of every member of $y$;
> - every subset of $y$ of cardinality less than that of $y$.

However, I was wondering, when Grothendieck initially introduced these universes:

- was he working in a formal theory, such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which he found insufficient and decided to augment with an axiom similar to Tarski's?
- or, was he working in naive set theory, which he nevertheless found to be insufficient for his purposes (perhaps thinking the existence of these sets was not guaranteed by intuition)?

I did some searching, but having not thoroughly combed the literature, I was not able to find the source(s) where he introduced universes; references are welcome.

Comment: Some references : [authorship-of-grothendieck-universes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117517/authorship-of-grothendieck-universes).